# Attempting to create a tag wiki when a user has hit the suggested edit limit should alert the user that no more edits can be suggested at this time

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

I ran into an issue on Gaming.SE where I attempted to create a tag wiki and wiki excerpt for a tag which did not have one already while I already have the maximum of five suggested edits in the queue.

Navigating to the tag page for the [survival planet tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survival-planet) provides a link to [create a tag wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/11276) for this tag. This link redirects to the [about page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/survival-planet/info) for this tag, without telling me that I can't submit an edit because I've reached the maximum number of suggested edits. Instead of silently redirecting, the page should alert me that I can't suggest any more edits until my suggestions are reviewed.

Comment: One of our users struck the same issue at [gis.se]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287447/show-banner-rather-than-having-create-tag-info-button-go-missing-when-user-has-5

Comment: I've had this issue on SO as well. Very confusing to see "The [tag] has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?" but no edit/create button.