# Show banner rather than having Create Tag info button go missing when user has 5 pending suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

At GIS, which I moderate, we have a Meta Q&A about [Why is it that I sometimes find I am unable to edit a tag](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/why-is-it-that-i-sometimes-find-i-am-unable-to-edit-a-tag) and I think the issue being discussed will be common to all sites.

When our user is editing tag wikis they are sometimes not provided with the `Create Tag info` button.

It seems like this is due to them encountering [Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits) and in particular the limit of:

> at-most 5 pending suggested edits per editor on graduated sites

Assuming that our analysis is correct, when an editor already has 5 suggested edits in the review queue, would it be possible for the tag wiki page to show a banner like this?

> You are currently unable to suggest edits to tag wikis because you
>   already have 5 suggested edits awaiting review.

I think that would be better than the `Create Tag info` button simply going missing.